# Copy a package to catkin workspace

Tags: ros, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to change a package I found: http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan and https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan

I need to make changes in every file, .h, .cpp, .... To do this I want to do a copy of this package to catkin workspace in order to make the changes without messing with the original package!

How can I do this? Is it ok for this package to have the same name as the previous one which I have installed with ROS?

****UPDATE****

I already have the package in my catkin workspace directory, thanks to @ahendrix!

Now I have one question:

- All the files, including the files from include folder, test folder and cfg folder are in the package directory: /catkin_ws/src/depthimage_to_laserscan . Is this ok? Should these files in these folders be inside the package folder directory along with the src folder?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189051/copy-a-package-to-catkin-workspace/) by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the source code for the package is on github, you can check out the source into your workspace with git clone:

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan.git
```

If you want to use a branch other than the github default, you can use `git checkout <branch>` to check out a specific branch. The branch used for the version of ROS that you're using should be documented on the package's wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-05**:
Hi! Sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean by branch?

I already have the package in my catkin workspace directory! Is it ok for this package to have the same name as the previous one which I have installed with ROS?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
For a definition of branches, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(revision_control) and http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is .

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
You've asked how to copy the package to your workspace, but it's already in your workspace? I'm confused. Can you describe how you have ROS installed?

**Comment by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) on 2014-08-05**:
I can't cite this, but I believe it is okay for the package to have the same name as the previous one; I believe ROS defaults to using the one in your workspace...

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-05**:
I used your command inside the directory I wanted and it copied the package to the directory I was in... My ROS distribution is hydro, does it copy the package for hydro automatically? What do you want to know about how I installed ROS? I didn't understand...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
ROS supports having the same package in different workspaces; this is called overlaying. Normally, this happens when one version of a package is installed in the system workspace (/opt/ros) and the user wants to have a copy in their local workspace (~/catkin_ws/).

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
The version of the package in the local workspace will be used instead of the version in the system workspace, if you have it in both places.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
The hydro version (branch) of the package is probably not checked out by default. The package's wiki page lists the `hydro-devel` branch for Hydro, so you should check out the hydro-devel branch.

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-05**:
Thank you @ahendrix! Also, all the files, including the files from include folder, test folder and cfg folder are in the package directory: /catkin_ws/src/depthimage_to_laserscan . Is this ok? Should these files in these folders be inside the package folder directory along with the src folder?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-05**:
The directory structure for the package should be exactly as it appears on github. It's probably right just the way it is.

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-05**:
Thank you!